# Check Android API level AT application launch?

Tags: android, api

Is there a way to check the Android API level before any activity gets called? The way I want to set up this app is that if the API level is below, say 15, the App launches one activity that mainly uses activities and simple layouts whereas if the API level is above or equal 15 it should open a different activity that uses a prettier layout and the features that come with higher API levels.

I know how to do it from the MainActivity (just with a simple if statement and checking the Build number) but can this be done before anything is called? Because if I have to cramp two completely different parts of the application into one Activity it will get *very* crowded in there...(And it wouldn't really be that elegant...)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Manifest will eventually stop you from implementing the code for let's say API 15, when the android device uses 11 for example. If the "prettier" features requre higher API level, then it will not be just a matter of if <-> else in the beginning.

Comment: Can't you set ignore flags to parts of your application which would only cause your application to crash if parts from higher API levels were to be run on lower API phones?

Comment: I think that the minSDK version in the Manifest bounds the whole aplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no any built-in feature that allows you to do it. The easiest workaround is to create a stub activity that will only start an appropriate activity dependeing on the current android version.

```
public class StubActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ICSActivity.class));
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, PreICSActivity.class));
        }

        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: I usually also add a `android:noHistory="true"` in the manifst to not let it persist in stack

Comment: @vmironov - I'm guessing then, that the contents of the `startActivity()` should also comply to the minSDK version in the manifest-right?

Comment: @g00dy, no. `ICSActivity` can use any features that were added on `ICS` regardless of `minSdk` version.

Comment: @g00dy, in case you are using `Eclipse`, make sure to add `@TargetApi(15)` anotation to `ICSActivity` declaration to prevent [`Lint`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html)'s warnings

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. I guess I'll try this out. Do you know how much this will slow down the opening process of the application?

Comment: @G00DY, nobody will ever notice the difference.